# Trying to get back values from a pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have this blog app, and Posts have Tags. I did an many to many relationship and it works good and fine to store, but can't get back its values when editing.

Let's see some code:

Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
  }
  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
  }
  public function comments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
  }
  public function marca()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Marca');
  }
  public function modelo()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modelo');
  }
  public function versao()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Versao');
  }
}
```

The PostController @create:

```
 $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;

        $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $post->body = $request->body;

        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')){
            $image = $request->file('featured_image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
            $post->image = $filename;

        }

        $post->save();

        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
```

And the PostController@edit:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post       = Post::find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();
    $tags = Tag::all();
    $tags2 = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tags2[$tag->id] = $tag->name;
    }
    $marcas     = Marca::all();
    $modelos    = Modelo::all();
    $versaos    = Versao::all(); 
    return view('manage.posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($categories)->withMarcas($marcas)->withTags($tags2)->withModelos($modelos)->withVersaos($versaos);
}
```

At last, but not least, the HTML:

```
 <label for="cambio">TAG</label>
                    <select class="custom-select select-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="{{ $tags->id }}">{{ $tags->name }}</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
```

The error is:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/marcellopato/Sites/CepCar2.0-BootStrap3.3/resources/views/manage/posts/edit.blade.php)
```

Comment: Hi did you try to loop over tags ?

Comment: Not really. I did this work once using Form-Helpers, but since is kind of obsolete...

Comment: Try my answer !!

Comment: @Maraboc It renders all the tags. Cool. But I need to markup the Tags that were created in the create section. Got it?
Sorry if I wasn't clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post       = Post::with('tags')->find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();
    $tags = Tag::all();
    $marcas     = Marca::all();
    $modelos    = Modelo::all();
    $versaos    = Versao::all(); 
    return view('manage.posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($categories)->withMarcas($marcas)->withModelos($modelos)->withVersaos($versaos);
}
```

In the view :

```
<label for="cambio">TAG</label>
<select class="custom-select select-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
     @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
          <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jacurtis and his classes of Vuejs.js, I found a way to solve my problem.

Some script:

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data : {   
      ... 
        coresSelected : {!! $versao->cores->pluck('id') !!},
      ...
}
```

On the HTML section:

```
<label>Cores Existentes</label><br>
                <select class="custom-select select-multi but-to-but" multiple="multiple" name="cor[]" v-model="coresSelected">
                  @foreach($cores as $cor)
                    <option :value="{{ $cor->id }}">{{ $cor->descricao }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
```

And the result is:

[Those are colors added on create section of my CorController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN1aq.png)

Thanks to you all!